# Core Data memory leak when I use UINavigationController

Tags: ios, core-data, memory-leaks, uinavigationcontroller

I used the Xcode template to create a Master-Detail app and I am using Core Data. I check the app with Instruments (memory leaks) and I see memory leaks when go back from Detail View to Master View.

Memory leaks appear when I:

1. select any row in a table and go from Master View to Detail View
2. edit value and click button clickSave in DetailView
3. click on button Back in UINavigationController

My code:

```
MasterViewController.m:
@implementation MasterViewController
.....
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        Event *object = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:object];
    }
}

DetailViewController.h:
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Event.h"

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) Event *detailItem;

@end


DetailViewController.m:
- (IBAction)clickSave:(id)sender {

    self.detailItem.myText = self.textView.text;

    NSError *error;
    if (![self.detailItem.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you testing on a device? I often see spikes on the Simulator which don't happen on a device. Also, if you are using ARC, i don;t see anything in the above that would/could leak

Comment: if I send the App to you, could you check it? Maybe error is in other place..

Comment: How big is the leak?  The iOS frameworks do have an occasional leak of 1kb or less.

Comment: Leaked Objects: _NSUndoStack 32 Bytes, _NSUndoStack 32 Bytes, _UITextUndoManager 48 Bytes. It leaks again and again when I try 1,2,3 steps.

Comment: On a device I see the same leaks: _UiTextUndoManager, _NSUndoStack, _NSUndoBeginMark, NSMutableRLEArray, __NSCFString.. etc.

Comment: I found strange thing. Memory leak exists only when I use UITextView. If I replace UITextView on UITextField - all memory leaks disappears.